# keep track of all logins and logouts

Tags: ssh, login

The system is using wtmp to keep track of all logins and logouts to the system. Since the new year, it doesn't keep track for more than a day. For example when I look at all logins I see the following:

```
$ last -i
myuser pts/1        xx.x.xx.xx      Tue Feb  4 11:25   still logged in   

wtmp begins Tue Feb  4 11:25:49 2014
```

But I want to see all logins for a much larger time than that, like how it worked before the new year. How can I go about doing that?